# How to add name of the user in admin_user model in ActiveAdmin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to add a new field called username to my admin_user model. I am using ActiveAdmin in my application. I am not sure how to add it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using these two commands:

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_admin_user username:string    

rake db:migrate
```

The first line is a shortcut for adding a field to a table (`add_username_to_admin_user`). It will produce something like this:

```
class AddUsernameToAdminUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :admin_users, :username, :string
  end
end
```

The second line applies the migration to your database.

You might also want to review the [migration documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) for more in-depth information (as always, Caveat Emptor: Rails documentation is notoriously out of date).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your schema (use `rails g migration`), update your DB (`rake db:migrate`) and then active admin will see the field.